# How to Iterate Twice over Map values in Java

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, mapping, naivebayes

I know there are other solutions out there but nothing is working for me.

Question: In my main method, I group together IDs by rating and make the rating the key and the rest of the info the value as a List. When I create the hashmap and put in the lists I can accurately print the contents of the hashmap. However, once I pass the map the evaluate method, the values are lost and I cannot iterate in the same way that I did in the main method, even though the logic is the same. I am not experienced with the Map class in java. Can somebody please help me figure out why when I pass the Map to my evaluate method that I can no longer iterate the Map?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Evaluate {

public static double grandTotal;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("testInput.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
    FileInputStream fs2 = new FileInputStream("testTest.txt");
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs2));
    String line;
    String line2;
    String[] bloop;
    String bleep;
    String flooper; 
    String splitter;
    String[] splitInput;
    List<String> oneStarList= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> twoStarList= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> threeStarList= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> fourStarList= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> fiveStarList= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> values2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            bloop = new String[10];
            bloop = line.split("\\s+");
            bleep = bloop[1].toString();
            flooper = (bloop[0]+" "+bloop[2]+" "+bloop[3]+" "+bloop[4]);
            if (bleep.equals("1")){
                oneStarList.add(flooper);
            }
            else if (bleep.equals("2")){
                twoStarList.add(flooper);
            }
            else if (bleep.equals("3")){
                threeStarList.add(flooper);
            }
            else if (bleep.equals("4")){
                fourStarList.add(flooper);
            }
            else if (bleep.equals("5")){
                fiveStarList.add(flooper);
            }
            grandTotal+=(Double.parseDouble(bloop[2]));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }

    Map<String,List<String>> hmap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    hmap.put("1",oneStarList);
    hmap.put("2", twoStarList);
    hmap.put("3", threeStarList);
    hmap.put("4", fourStarList);
    hmap.put("5", fiveStarList);


    while ((line2=br2.readLine()) != null) {
        splitInput = new String[5];
        splitInput = line2.split("\\s+");
        evaluate(splitInput[0],splitInput[1],hmap);
    }
    br.close();
    br2.close();
}

public static void evaluate(String movID, String usrID, Map<String,List<String>> hash) throws Exception{

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outputTest.txt");
    BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] floop;
    String fleep;
    int movIDtotal=0;
    int usrIDtotal=0;
    int totalValues=0;
    double pmovIDStar=0;
    double pusrIDStar=0;
    double pmovID=0;
    double pusrID=0;
    double numID=0;
    double keyTotalProb=0;
    String keyOutputStr;
    String keyHold;

    final Set<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> entries = hash.entrySet();

    for (String key : hash.keySet()){
        values = hash.get(key);
        System.out.println(key + ":");
        for (int i=0;i<values.size();i++){
            System.out.println(values.get(i));
            floop = new String[5];
            fleep = values.get(i);
            floop = fleep.split("\\s+");
            if (movID.equals(floop[0])){
                movIDtotal++;
                totalValues++;
            }
            if (usrID.equals(floop[0])){
                usrIDtotal++;
                totalValues++;
            }
        }
        values.clear();
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry: entries){
        values= entry.getValue();
        keyHold = entry.getKey();
        for (int j=0;j<values.size();j++){

            floop = new String[5];
            fleep = values.get(j);
            floop = fleep.split("\\s+");
            if (movID.equals(floop[0])){
                pmovIDStar = Double.parseDouble(floop[3]);
                numID = Double.parseDouble(floop[1]);
                pmovID = (numID/movIDtotal);
            }
            if (usrID.equals(floop[0])){
                pusrIDStar = Double.parseDouble(floop[3]);
                numID = Double.parseDouble(floop[1]);
                pusrID = (numID/usrIDtotal);
            }
        }
        keyTotalProb = ((totalValues/grandTotal)*(pmovIDStar)*(pusrIDStar))/(pusrID*pmovID);
        keyOutputStr = Double.toString(keyTotalProb);
        outputList.add(keyHold);
        outputList.add(keyOutputStr);
        values.clear();
    }

    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int m=0;m<outputList.size();m+=2){
        double coolguy = Double.parseDouble(outputList.get(m+1));
        int index = 0;
        if(coolguy>max){
            max = coolguy;
            index = m;
        }

        try {
            bwr.write(String.format("%-1s %-1s %-1s%n", movID,usrID,outputList.get(index)));
            bwr.close();
            fw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Backup info: I'm trying to build a java program that essentially performs the final stage of the Naive Bayes algorithm to predict user ratings (1-5) for movies. I have used MapReduce to train data and now I have an input file where each line contains a string containing information in this order without the commas (movie or user id,rating , number of times rating and ID occur together in total, number of times ID occurs in total, probability that ID and rating occur together out of all ratings for ID). Essentially this is the classification stage.

Answer (score 0):

1. never suppress excetions. especially when you do coding/debugging.

   `catch (Exception e){    }` is very bad practice
2. When you do:

   `final Set<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> entries = hash.entrySet();`

it does not copy `hash.entrySet` to `entries`. It creates another reference to it.
 same is for `values= entry.getValue();`

3. then what do you expect after your first loop (and others too)? 
   when you do:

   `values.clear();`

   your values gone from the lists which are in `hash` and since `entries` is just a reference to `hash.entrySet()` you have what you've done - empty lists.